# Сохранить последние 10 строк в другом (новом) файле

Tags: python, python-2.x

Сделать функцию `function()` которая принимает имя файла и сохранить последние 10 строк (или меньше) в другом файле с именем `truncated_% имя_файла%`.

Например, последние 10 строк (или меньше) из файла `lorem.txt` должны быть скопированы в новый `truncated_lorem.txt`.

Мои варианты:

Вариант 1

```
def function(filename, new_filename, number_of_lines=0):
    if number_of_lines is None or number_of_lines == 0:
        print "if number_of_lines is None or 0, file or directory with file don't created"
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(new_filename)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(new_filename))
    file_ = open(filename)
    new_file_ = open(new_filename, "w")
    for lines in deque(file_, number_of_lines):
        new_file_.write(lines)

    file_.close()
    new_file_.close()


function("A:lorem.txt", "A:truncated_lorem.txt", 10)
```

Вариант 2

```
lorem = os.path.abspath("lorem.txt")

def function(filename):

    with open(filename, "r") as file_:
        list_of_lines = list(file_)

    with open("truncated_" + os.path.basename(filename), 'w') as file_:
        for lines in list_of_lines[-10::]:
            file_.write(lines)

function(lorem)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш первый вариант отлично использует [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.deque), позволяя работать с файлами, превышающими размер оперативной памяти.

Можно немного упростить его воспользовавшись модулем [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```
from pathlib2 import Path
from collections import deque

def copy_bottom_lines(filename, lines=10, file_prefix='truncated_'):
    fin = Path(filename).absolute()
    q = deque(fin.open(), maxlen=lines)
    fout = fin.parent / (file_prefix + fin.name)
    fout.write_text(''.join(list(q)))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def foo(from_file, to_file, count):
    with open(from_file) as f, open(to_file, 'w') as t:
        t.writelines(f.readlines()[-count:])
```

Comment: Если минусуете ответ, аргументируйте почему

Comment: А кто минусует? Я вижу 0!

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user

Comment: пожалуйста, добавьте пару слов о том, как работает ваше решение

Comment: @mymedia Тут нечего объяснять, открыли два файла один прочли в другой записали.